# Turning a char sequence into a picture in a text field (smileys)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, user-input

Say I have a text field on a website. How could I programmatically enable the user to write the letters " :) " and then turn these two chars into an actual smiley picture (.gif) in the editor?

I am kind of stuck, as I don't know how I would watch the text field for this, and also how to insert the picture at the right place?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a picture in a normal text field. You need something like https://www.tinymce.com/

That said, you could replace :) with a unicode smiley ☺ - here is a list:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728

then you can do

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("inp").onkeyup = function() {
    var text = this.value;
    if (text) this.value = text.replace(/:\)/g, "☺");
  }
}
```

```html
Try typing <i>Hi there:)</i>: <input type="text" id="inp" value="" />
```